# PHP/SQL searching in database

Tags: php, mysql, search

I've been doing a simple php code to search for stuff inside a database. Now here's my question. For example in the database there is a Name "John Anthony Jaynes" but I only know the name "John Jaynes". No results come out because "Anthony" is in the middle of John and Jaynes. I don't know how to start coding because I don't know where to start. I am using LIKE so if I type "Jo Jay" it should also work "Jo" is from John and "Jay" is for Jaynes. As long as they are in order it would work like "Jo An Jay" should work but "Jo Jay An" shouldnt't. Is it even possible? Thank you very much! here's my SQL code!

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * 
FROM brochureinfo 
WHERE sku LIKE '%".$_GET['search']."%' || name LIKE '%".$_GET['search']."%' 
ORDER BY name";
```

$_GET['search'] is just the value coming from the textbox. thanks for the help guys!

[image: Here is the table]

Comment: Adding a table structure that you are talking about should be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are talking about full text search --
Below query may provide you the idea --

```
SELECT * FROM brochureinfo WHERE match(sku,name) against('your search string')
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html